# C# get NumberFormatInfo

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I want to read a string, get a specific number from the string, multiply this by a double and replace the old by the new string-number.
After the multiplication, the format of the number changes

Example: original format 8.08000e+14

Multiplication by, lets say two, returns: 1.616E+15

I want the new number to have exactly the format of the old number (would be 1.61600e+15, could be done for instance using String.Format), but for doing so, I need to get the format of the old number first (this format is not always the same). How can I get this format info?

Comment: is it always in the E-notation ?

Comment: Are you worried about the format itself (scientific notation vs. regular decimal)? Or just concerned with the significant digits of the calculation?

Comment: @EricSondergard I get that point. How do you know that the original format is not always in the E-notation?

Comment: @MongZhu Sorry, the same thing just dawned on me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather hacky approach:

Assuming that your original format is in the e-notation. You could find the amount of digits between the `.` and `e` Then use the number for the transformation again into the e-notation.

Here is a small example:

```
string test = "4.08123000E+14";

//string test = "8.08000e+14";          

double test_as_double = Convert.ToDouble(test);

test_as_double *= 2.0;

// find all digits between . and e or E
string old_format = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(test, @".\d+[e|E]").Value;

// take the amount of digits without the . and e
int number_of_digits = old_format.Length-2;

// create the new number-string with the old folmar
string new_old_Format = test_as_double.ToString("E" + number_of_digits.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```